# Webservices: Request-Response Mapper

Tags: java, web-services, design-patterns, jakarta-ee

This is more of a design-pattern question.

My client application [implemented and will run both as part of a scheduled batch job as well as a message processing application] makes SOAP over HTTP calls to a third party Engine to get some membership data. Since the underlying binding is done thought JAX-RPC, my SOAP response is eventually converted / copied into the generated client stubs.

Now, my question - Is it better to maintain my own domain objects and copy the data from the response objects of the service or is it OK if I can directly use the stub objects to do other processing!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is going to be somewhat subjective. I prefer to always translate to my own domain objects in case I ever need to swap out the web service implementation. If they ever change over to RESTful web services or just simply change up their wsdl on a version upgrade, you may be out of luck if you are using the stub classes throughout your application.

There are cons to this practice though:

1. You will need to maintain a similar set of classes
2. If the service never changes, you wont see any returns on your effort
3. You can always change this later if it proves useful

Comment: An argument against using stub classes is that you may have to change Web Services framework (or significant version) and starting from the WSDL, these may generate different stubs.

Having a set of DTOs as smp7d suggested is good isolation layer, but I hope you objects are not too complex: writing the transfers from stubs to DTOs is a real pain.